# Default Filename for GetOpenFilename

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to set a default filename in `GetOpenFilename`.  I'm using `GetOpenFilename` because it was in an example for using UNC paths (which I require) and from what I've read you cannot do that with `ChDir` or `ChDrive` using `FileDialog`.  Is there anything that exists that will allow presetting of the filename and work with UNC paths?

I've tried sticking the filename into the `FileFilter` section of `GetOpenFilename` and that does not work.  From what I have found it looks like this may not be possible but my limited knowledge of VBA may be the issue as well.

I'm stuck with using UNC because the data is located on a network and not everyone maps it to the same drive or even maps it at all.

Comment: Help us to help you, **post your current code.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel if you look in `Application.Dialogs()` you'll find a long list of predefined dialog boxes used in Excel that you can call upon. `GetOpenFilename` is the same situation, because it is predefined, the customization options are minimal.

To use the generic file dialog box (i.e. not custom within Excel) you can use `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)`, this will allow for further customisation including the initial filename text.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim Dlg As FileDialog

Set Dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    Dlg.InitialFileName = "Sample"
    Dlg.Show
Set Dlg = Nothing

End Sub
```